# Spark While Drilling

Tags: drill

I have purchased a Bosch GSB 550 Professional drill.

While drilling, I have seen sparks inside the drilling machine, is it common or is it a matter of concern.

Appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The small sparks are normal with carbon brushed motors. When new as the brushes seat on the armature there may be more small sparks than normal. One way to help the brushes seat is to run the motor for a few minutes without a load, Those will help the armature and brushes to polish and seat together. There will always be small sparks as the armature rotates this is normal for brush based motors.

Comment: A lot of sparks after the break-in would indicate a cracked/broken brush, though. Don't ignore it if it goes on for a while.